# PHP and Large CSV file, error on load and formatting

Tags: php, csv, import

I have input / output devices in the company to calculate the employee's real time. The problem is that the device database is in the * .tps file. So I decided to copy the * .tps file once a day and use java to convert the file to * .csv. I am now trying to load this file and display it in a table using PHP and HTML. (Ultimately, this data will be sent to MySQL - Only new lines, the rest will be skipped) - I am trying to prepare data for this by conveniently doing INSERT Query.

Problem:
The CSV file has 500k records, its weight is 70MB. My script shows an error after some 4-5 minutes of code execution - "Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in". Do you have any idea so that despite the fact that it will take him even 30 minutes do not interrupt but continue?

The second problem is that a blank   appears to me, I have no idea why.

MyCode:

```
<?php $start_time = microtime(true); ?>
<table>
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("./AdamMultiTasking/Converted Database/DB_After.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $td = 0;
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>","Line #",$row,"</td>";
        $row++;
        for ($recordcount=0; $recordcount < $num; $recordcount++) {
        $td++;

            if($td == 1){
                echo "<td id='ID'>".str_replace(' ', '', $data[$recordcount]) . "<td>";
            }
            if($td == 6){
                echo "<td id='EmplNo'>".str_replace(' ', '', $data[$recordcount]) . "<td>";
            }
            if($td == 7){
                echo "<td id='Date'>".str_replace(' ', '', $data[$recordcount]) . "<td>";
            }
            if($td == 8){
                echo "<td id='Time'>".str_replace(' ', '', $data[$recordcount]) . "<td>";
            }
            if($td == 10){
                echo "<td id='Direction'>".str_replace(' ', '', $data[$recordcount]) . "<td>";
            }

        }
        $td = 0;
        echo "</tr>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>
</table>
This page was generated in <?php echo(number_format(microtime(true) - $start_time, 2)); ?> seconds.
```

There are 5 IFs in the loop that check the id of the column because the file has a lot more columns than it needs. I only want to download the required values, that's why they are IF

Please, let me know if you can help me with it and maybe you have a better idea how to do it faster? Maybe using jQuery? I don't know, I don't have that much experience

Thank you

EDIT:

CSV sample:

```
"Rec No","Guid","Recordnumber","Site","Cardnumber","Empnumber","Date","Time","Device","Direction","Type","Status","Deleted","User","Accessdata","Jobdata","Originaldate","Originaltime","Originaldirection","Company","Branch","Department","Costcenter","Category","Scale","Emptype","Workgroup","Job","Quantity","Jobdata1","Clo:comment"
13,"Here}WR@tdLKTYDf",0,"Here","2012      ","2012      ",75261,2932601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
16,"Here}WR@[^VKdpB[",0,"Here","6224      ","6224      ",75261,2973401,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
17,"Here}WR@LLZKsWzJ",0,"Here","6074      ","6074      ",75261,2988601,"A       ","I"," ","A"," ","            ",0,0,0,0," ",0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,"          ",0,"          ",""
```

Pic about empty td tags
[image]

Comment: You can use set_time_limit(timeInSec);, if you are sure for some max time. replace timeInSec with time value in sec. Please read https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

Comment: set_time_limit(0) or  ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); they can solve your problem, add them above your script. They remove any time restriction.